# Why is my Blender Rigify Rig Shoulder/Arm Pinching and Twisting?

Tags: rigging, armature, rigify

So I am very new to Character modeling and rigging, so I decided to try Rigify, specifically the basic human rig. The issue I am having is that the arm tends to twist and really pinch at the shoulder, and I was wondering what the problem could be.[image]

[google drive link for blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NuWHUiQrZnjqeytfA5o_tuwSKah-n1Eu/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: due to your topology, you need to add more loopcuts or even more polygons to your model for it to actually work, also some movement are limited based on what topology you created